# ArrayAdapter is changed but not reflected in UI

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have been working on ListView and ArrayAdapter. Now I got Stuck while making change in my ArrayAdapter.

I'm using an AsyncTack to update the UI element i.e. ListView, an adapter to the ListView is set in onCreate() method initially, but I'm about to change the array adapter in onPostExecute() method of AsyncTask.

**Here is the code bellow**

```
ListView mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.dataListView);
vAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_data,strings);
mLisstView.setAdapter(vAdapter);
```

AsyncTask

```
public class getDataFromServer extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String[]>{


        public getDataFromServer() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... parm) {
            // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
            // so that they can be closed in the finally block.

            if(parm.length == 0){
                return null;
            }

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
            String getJsonStr = null;

            try {
                final String FORECAST_BASE_URL="http://myUrlToServer?";
                final String QUERY_PARAM ="query";
                final String FORMAT_PARAM ="mode";
                final String UNITS_PARAM ="units";

                Uri baseUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                            .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM,parm[0])
                            .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
                            .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM,units)
                            .build();

                Log.v("build Url: ",baseUri.toString());
                URL url = new URL(baseUri.toString());

                // Create the request and open the connection
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    return null;
                }
                getJsonStr = buffer.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {                
                return null;
            } finally{
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e("Found in trouble", "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            try {
                return getWeatherDataFromJson(getJsonStr,numDays);
            }catch(JSONException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] strings) {
            super.onPostExecute(strings);

            for(String s : strings)
                Log.v("@ onPostExecute",s);

            vAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_data,strings);
            vAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            /*if(strings != null){
                vAdapter.clear();
                for(String dayForecast : strings){
                    vAdapter.add(dayForecast);
                }
            }*/

        }
    }
```

NOTE: the commented code in onPostExecute() method is also correct by means of logic but generating exception as UnsupportedOperationException while vAdapter.clear()

Comment: No need to create adapter reference again. You just update the array, then call notifyDataSetChanged() on adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found the solution.
I have used array while creating adapter in onCreate() method and trying to clear the adapter as vAdapter.clear() which is not possible. so to do this I just change the array with the List

**at onCreate() method**

```
String[] mArray = {"element1","element2",.....};
List<String> mList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(mArray));
vAdapter = new ArrayAdappter(getActivity(),R.layout.list_item_data,mList);
```

**at onPostExecute() method**

```
vAdapter.clear();
vAdapter.addAll(strings);
```

thank you to all.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

**onPostExecute()** should looks like below:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String[] strings) {
super.onPostExecute(strings);

   for(String s : strings)
      Log.v("@ onPostExecute",s);

    vAdapter.clear();
    vAdapter.addAll(strings);
    vAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

That's it.

Comment: sorry for being late, and Yes, you are right but i need to keep the default data that comes from my local String[] variable and the new one which is the result after executing AsyncTask